# PHPExcel thousand separator remove

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am inserting a large amount of data to database through excel file.
I can never be sure how the cells in excel will be formatted because there are multiple people changing and uploading that file.
I can't seem to get the number formatting in PHPExcel to work. I would like to format the values in cells to numbers without thousand separator. I know I am missing something really obvious, but I would really appreciate any help.
I've added two methods I have tried in the code, also I have search this subject, but nothing seems to work.

```
require_once '../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load( $inputFileName );
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray( null, true, true, true );

$i = 1;

foreach ( $sheetData as $key => $data ) {

  if ( $key > 2 && $data['A'] != '' ) {
    $article = $data['A'];
    foreach ( $data as $col => $value ) {
        // this does not work
        //$val = $sheetData->getStyle($col.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0');
        // this does not work either
        //$sheetData->getStyle($col.':'.$i)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );*/
         if ( $col != 'A' && $value != '' && $value != '0' && $value != '-' ) {
            echo $val.'<br>';
            // database insert...
         }
      }
  }
  $i++;
}
```

With the examples that did not work it gives me errors:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class `PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat` could not be converted to string in.

Comment: You're asking the toArray() method to return formatted data: perhaps returning it unformatted might be a better option

Comment: Note that `$sheetData` is a simple PHP array of scalar values, not objects; and you can't call a getStyle() method on a scalars

Comment: An alternative is looping through the worksheet reading the individual cells, rather than generating an array from the worksheet and looping through that array... it's better for the memory usage as well

Comment: I'll have to see how to make that work because of the data I need to get from that file.